# Rails - where to put files that are not part of the deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to do a lot of conditioning of the data that will seed my rails database. This is a one-shot activity before deployment, never used after deployment, but I want to keep the programs I use for it within the projects configuration management (mainly for the sake of an audit trail for where the seed data came from).

Where is the canonical place in a Rails app for such support files that don't form part of the application?

Comment: What are you using for deployment? I would think you could just exclude a folder at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Seed data should go in `db/seed.rb`. You can learn more about seed data [in the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

Comment: It's not seed data. It's code that takes data from a different data source, checks it, and turns it into seed data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with adding all these items to your repository is that not only will it make the checked in code large, also you will have to clean the code each time after deploy.

I do not think such items should be checked in. Personally, I place all such items in public data, upload it for first deploy and then next deploy will no longer have this folder as the deployment using capistrano will not link to the data folder anymore.

This way the data can stay in the shared folder on the server should you need it again but not in your repository.

Comment: That seems to be the opposite of what I want - I want it under configuration control and so in my git repository, but I don't want it cluttering up the server. Is there nowhere I can put it that won't get uploaded to the server? After all, I don't want my tests uploaded either, but I have those under revision control.

Comment: I have seen people create folders in the repository but outside of the project and then add all these items in there. But then they had to give an explicit folder link as a URL to be deployed. That was possible with SVN. I am sorry but cannot say if git will allow you to do the same.